# PowerShell ForEach-Object Parallel RAM Memory Keeps Growing

Tags: microsoft, garbage-collecting, parallel-computing, powershell-v7

Using PS 7.3.4
The code works fine without errors.

**Issue** - the RAM consumed by the script keeps growing.  How do I release the RAM?  How do I see what is consuming the RAM?  Any suggestions will be greatly apprciated.

**Memory results after processing batches of 10K input**

**End of 1st group of 10K memory results.**

For loop memory used BEFORE collection: 1,208,928,432

For loop memory used AFTER full collection: 512,021,912

**End of 2nd group of 10K memory results.**

For loop memory used BEFORE collection: 1,160,822,952

For loop memory used AFTER full collection: 929,192,840

**End of 3rd group of 10K memory results.**

For loop memory used BEFORE collection: 2,168,048,568

For loop memory used AFTER full collection: 1,355,942,720

. . .

**End of 8th group of 10K memory results.**

For loop memory used BEFORE collection: 12,562,155,960

For loop memory used AFTER full collection: 11,765,923,128

**End of 9th group of 10K memory results.**

For loop memory used BEFORE collection: 13,170,803,320

For loop memory used AFTER full collection: 12,166,518,384

[int]$i3 = 1

## Loop through all of the arrayLists in $allArrays.  Each arrayList inside $allArrays contains 10K user ids.

Do {

```
$allArrays[$i3] | ForEach-Object -Parallel {

# Contains code to call Microsoft graph API, get some info and write to file.

# At end of script, write all results to arrayList.
# Write all arrayLists to a file.
# Empty all arrayLists using arrayList.Clear()

# # Code to track variables that keep growing in size INSIDE foreach parallel.  Unfortunately the variables information returned does not show any variables exceeding a length of 3000.  Even after processing 200K input lines.
$varSize = get-variable -Name *
for ($i=0; $i -lt $varSize.Count; $i++)
    {
        if($varSize[$i].Value -and ($varSize[$i].Value.ToString().Length -gt 3000)){Write-host -ForegroundColor gray "`n`rDisplaying all variables with a length greater than 50"; Write-host -ForegroundColor gray "Name: $($($varSize[$i]).Name) `tLength: $($varSize[$i].Value.ToString().Length)"}
    }

}
# Function called to renew access token.
renewAccessToken

$memBefore = '{0:N0}' -f $([System.GC]::GetTotalMemory($false))
write-host -ForegroundColor Gray "`n`rFor loop memory used BEFORE collection: $memBefore - $(getTimestamp)"
[System.GC]::Collect()
[GC]::Collect()
[GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
$memAfter = '{0:N0}' -f $([System.GC]::GetTotalMemory($true))
write-host -ForegroundColor Gray "For loop memory used AFTER full collection: $memAfter - $(getTimestamp)"

# Code to track variables that keep growing in size OUTSIDE foreach parallel.  Unfortunately the variables information returned does not show any variables exceeding a length of 100.  Even after processing 200K input lines.
$varSize = get-variable -Name *
for ($i=0; $i -lt $varSize.Count; $i++)
    {
        if($varSize[$i].Value -and ($varSize[$i].Value.ToString().Length -gt 50)){Write-host -ForegroundColor gray "`n`rDisplaying all variables with a length greater than 50"; Write-host -ForegroundColor gray "Name: $($($varSize[$i]).Name) `tLength: $($varSize[$i].Value.ToString().Length)"}
    }
        
$i3++

} while(($allArrays.Count + 1) -ne $i3)
```